# How to solve thin faces problem to make the model printable

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

I modeling a dragon to print it 3d now I am preparing it to make it ready for 3d printing, the problem is I don't know how to fix the thin faces problem that gives me the toolbox addon. the following show the problem:
[image: Thin faces]

[blend. file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XEhaE1uuTMOtQYH44tA_vIrX3gV5K3UG/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hello, does it mean that these parts are too thin and won't be correctly printed?

Comment: yes, it means that.

Comment: You may want to extrude the thin faces to a thickness of at-least 0.2-0.4mm thick.

Comment: You can try a displace modifier with a low value. Add a vertex group as the modifier influence and go into weight paint and paint the nails red

Comment: it doesn't work.

Comment: Try to Fatten them https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/transform/shrink-fatten.html